# Resolve own address

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm connecting to a Mail-Server (IMAP) where the address of a postbox is not equal to the username that one uses to login.

For instance, to connect to the postbox with address `myaddress@myhost.com`, the code would look like this:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("mail.myhost.local", "user123", "pass");
```

Note that the user-name is different from the address.

How can the email-address of a specific user-host be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it can't.  The user has to tell you both.